# How to set a different reference build or set dynamic thresholds to Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a master job that builds the master branch and various plugins ex.warnings plugin tracks the  counts of warnings detected in master.

Then we have a gerrit job that build the gerrit patches.The warnings plugin and other plugins by default compare delta against previous successful gerrit build. But we want to make compare warnings counts against the master build instead. Is there some known way to specify to use a different job as reference?

I can think of following roundabout ways.

1. Execute post-build script in master job that will update the
   thresholds in the gerrit job config.xml and reload.
2. Set dynamic thresholds with job parameters..but will not work if plugin will not accept parameter variables as thresholds.

Does someone know other or better solutions to this?

Comment: Would you able to find a way to do this ?

Comment: No. I could not find a solution to this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way how to use a different job as a reference in warnings-ng-plugin.

It can be done like this in the declarative pipeline syntax:

```
recordIssues tool: java(), referenceJobName: 'my-project/master'
```

More information in the documentation: https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#control-the-selection-of-the-reference-build-baseline